# Operation between two dataframe with different size in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to sum two dataframe with different size in R.

```
> x = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(5,6,7))
> y = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1))

> x
  a b
1 1 5
2 2 6
3 3 7

> y
  x
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

The result I want is,

```
> 
  a b
1 2 6
2 3 7
3 4 8
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `setNames(do.call('cbind', apply(x, 2, function(col) col + y)), c('a','b'))`

Comment: `x + unlist(y)` will do it.

Comment: @lmo I really like the elegance of that answer. The difference between a vector and a one-column dataframe is hard for a lot of R beginners to grasp.

Comment: Or just `x+y$x` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe easiest to convert y to a vector with `unlist` and then perform the operation. Here, the vector in `unlist(y)` will be recycled over the columns of the data.frame x.

```
x + unlist(y)
  a b
1 2 6
2 3 7
3 4 8
```

As a side note, data.frames are a special type of list object and sometimes performing operations on lists can be a bit more involved. On the otherhand, they tend to work fairly well with vectors as long as the dimensions line up (here, as long as the vector has the same length as the number of rows in the data.frame).

Answer (score 3):

We can make the dimensions same and then get the sum

```
x + rep(y, ncol(x))
#  a b
#1 2 6
#2 3 7
#3 4 8
```

---

Or another option is `sweep`

```
sweep(x, y$x, 1, `+`)
#  a b
#1 2 6
#2 3 7
#3 4 8
```

Comment: Liked your solution.